# HTML &nbsp character does not provide a color for cursor effect on vue

Tags: html, css, vue.js

I was following the tutorial on https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZIbASNgVMlQ for typewriter effect in vue and I cant seem to make the cursor visible on my screen in my web browser ( have tried chrome and Edge ), the syntax is as follows:

```css
.typing-effect .typed-text {
    color: #e97110;
}
      
.cursor {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 3px;
    margin-left: 3px;
    background-color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<p class="text-medium typing-effect">This is a typewriter effect
    <span class="typed-text">Test</span>
    <span class="cursor">&nbsp;</span>
</p>
```

And this is how it looks currently :
[how it looks now][1]

How it should look : [how it should looks][2]

The difference being that there is a cursor (white line) in the second photo, where there is no white line on the first one.

Another this is that when I insert some text in the cursor span, the white line shows up, but it did not shows up when there is only `&nbsp` character, and when I copy paste the entire code from tutorial, the white line still not show up.

Please kindly help, thank you in advance

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please provide a working example. But on firsthand it looks like your `.cursor` has no height so try adding `height: 100%;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vue has the weird feature that it replaces non-breaking spaces with regular spaces. If you need a non-breaking space use `{{ "\xA0" }}` instead of `&nbsp;`

Answer (score 1):

Use a `border-left` definition on the `.cursor` class or use a `background-color` other than white (i.e. other than the background of the parent element).

1.) using `border-left`:

```css
.typing-effect .typed-text {
  color: #e97110;
}

.typing-effect .cursor {
  display: inline-block;
  border-left: 3px solid red;
}
```

```html
<p class="text-medium typing-effect">This is a typewriter effect
  <span class="typed-text">Test</span>
  <span class="cursor">&nbsp;</span>
</p>
```

2.) Using `background-color`(other than white) and `width`:

```css
.typing-effect .typed-text {
  color: #e97110;
}

.typing-effect .cursor {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 3px;
  margin-left: 3px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<p class="text-medium typing-effect">This is a typewriter effect
  <span class="typed-text">Test</span>
  <span class="cursor">&nbsp;</span>
</p>
```